# What’s the simplest way to prove that the polynomial $f(z)=z^4 + z^3 + z^2 +2z +3$ has no real zero?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, factoring, quartics

I have managed to write the polynomial mentioned in the title as a sum of squares as follows:

$$ z^4 + z^3 + z^2 +2z +3 = \left( z^2 + \frac12 z - \frac18 \right)^2 + \left( z + \frac{17}{16} \right)^2 + \frac{475}{256} $$

Is this the simplest way to prove that it has no real zero, or is there another way that is simpler?

Update. The first comment below, written by Piquito, seems interesting, but I don't understand why the inequality would be true for all real z. Can someone explain it?

Comment: If $f(z)$ is the given polynomial we have $f(z)=\dfrac{z^5-1}{z-1}+(z+2)\gt0$

Comment: Why was the improvement (adding the non-answer to the question) removed? The question, which was reasonable, is now a [PSQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33854).

Comment: Yes, but I saw the qustion with the edit added.

Comment: @Piquito Nice way to rewrite the polynomial, but why is the inequality true for all real z?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a completely elementary proof (without calculus, complicated calculations or tricky factorizations):

- For $z\geq 0$, we have
  $$z^4 + z^3 + z^2 +2z +3\geq 3.$$
  Therefore, there is no real zero in the interval $[0,\infty)$.
- For $-1\leq z\leq 0$, we have (multiplying by $z^2$) $-z^2\leq z^3$. Then,
  $$z^4 + z^3 + z^2 +2z +3\geq z^4 + (-z^2) + z^2 +2(-1) +3=z^4+1>1.$$
  Therefore, there is no real zero in the interval $[-1,0]$.
- For $z\leq -1$, we have (multiplying by $z^3$) $z^4\geq-z^3$. Then,
  $$z^4 + z^3 + z^2 +2z +3\geq(-z^3) + z^3 + z^2 +2z +3= z^2 +2z +3>0.$$
  Therefore, there is no real zero in the interval $(-\infty,-1]$.

Comment: Very nice proof, but maybe the last, strict inequality is not obvious on an elementary level.

Comment: @AA Well, it requires the knowledge of the graph of quadratic function (in this case, concave upward due to positive leading coefficient, without root due to negative discriminant).

Comment: @AA Or we can use these estimates (sum of positive terms is positive):

$z²+2z+3=z(z+1)+(z+3)>0$ for $z$ in $[-3,-1]$;

$z²+2z+3=z(z+2)+3>0$ for $z$ in $(-\infty,-2]$.

Thus $>0$ in $(-\infty,-1]$.

But this is a kind of tricky factorizarion, which I tried to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the first two terms with $\left(z^2+\frac12z\right)^2$:
$$
z^4+z^3+z^2+2z+3-\left(z^2+\frac12z\right)^2=\frac34z^2+2z+3\tag1
$$
Remove the first two terms of $\frac34z^2+2z+3$ with $\frac34\left(z+\frac43\right)^2$:
$$
\frac34z^2+2z+3-\frac34\left(z+\frac43\right)^2=\frac53\tag2
$$
Thus, we get
$$
z^4+z^3+z^2+2z+3=\left(z^2+\frac12z\right)^2+\frac34\left(z+\frac43\right)^2+\frac53\tag3
$$

Comment: Elegant way of writing this particular polynomial as a sum of squares, but what happens if you try to do something similar with a polynomial such as z^4 - 2z^3 + 16? If you remove the first two terms with (z^2 - z)^2 then you are left with -z^2 + 16, and what to do from there? How to get rid of the -z^2 term?

Comment: Sometimes, we can't only use binomials: $z^4-2z^3+16=\left(z^2-z-1\right)^2+(z-1)^2+14$

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the polynomial as follows :

$$
\begin{align}P(z):=\left(z^4+z^3+z+1\right)+\left(z^2+z+2\right)\end{align}
$$

Then, you have :

$$
\begin{align}z^3\left(z+1\right)+(z+1)+\left(z^2+z+2\right)\end{align}
$$

or

$$
\begin{align}(z+1)\left(z^3+1\right)+(z^2+z+2)\end{align}
$$

Use the [*sum of cubes*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_cubes) formula $z^3+1=(z+1)(z^2-z+1)$, which leads to :

$$
\begin{align}(z+1)^2\underbrace{\left(z^2-z+1\right)}_{\color{#c00}{\Delta_z<0}}+\underbrace {\left(z^2+z+2\right)}_{\color{#c00}{\Delta_z<0}}>0\end{align}
$$

for all $z\in\mathbb R$ . Therefore, $P(z)>0,\thinspace \thinspace \forall z \in\mathbb R\thinspace .$

This completes the answer .

---

Equivalently if you wish, convert both $\color{#c00}{\Delta_z}$ to *completing the square*, then you reach the following [*sum of squares*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares) :

$$
\begin{align}\left(z+1\right)^2\left(z-\frac 12\right)^2+\frac 34\left(z+1\right)^2+\left(z+\frac 12\right)^2+\frac 74\end{align}
$$

which is equivalent to :

$$
\begin{align}\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\left(z^2+\frac 12z-\frac 12\right)^2+\frac {1}{28}\left(7z+5\right)^2+\frac {13}{7}\thinspace .}\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave this answer here, if it works for you .

---

Observe that :

$$
\begin{align}&z^4+z^3+z^2+2z+3\\
=\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace &\color{red}{z^2}(z^2+z+1)+2\color{red}{z}+3\end{align}
$$

Then you have :

$$
\begin{align}\Delta_{\color{red}{z}}&=1-3(z^2+z+1)\\
&=-\underbrace {(3\color{blue}{z^2}+3\color{blue}{z}+2)}_{\Delta_{\color{blue}{z}}\thinspace<\thinspace0}\\
&<0\thinspace\thinspace,\forall z\in\mathbb R\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

which completes the answer .

---

$\rm {Explanation:}$

We rewrote the polynomial as a quadratic polynomial respect to the $\color{red}{z}$ . Next, we looked at the general discriminant of the equation with respect to $\color{red}{z}$ . We have shown that, this discriminant is always negative . Thus, you're done .

Comment: Please, explain the downvote, if possible . Because,  I am ready to expand any step . Thank you .

Comment: (+1) This seems like an odd way to use the discriminant, with the independent variable in the coefficients. However, if there is a root, $z_0$, then definitely $z^2(z_0^2+z_0+1)+2z+3$ would also have $z_0$ as a root. So this method works.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you for your time, indeed.  I was very curious to know if the method would work.  From here  we can *complete the square* with respect to $\color{red}{z}$, am I right?  I guess this is a something cleaner ?

Comment: @robjohn Do you think, is it worth to add [these](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4668/460967) further details to above answer ?

Comment: The explanation provided is questionable. The polynomial is *not* rewritten as a quadratic polynomial in $z$, it is reorganized to *look* like a quadratic polynomial (using colors). Note that when I commented, I used a root $z_0$, different from $z$, to give an actual quadratic in $z$. Then we can derive the result you were after. I have trouble following your completion of squares for the same reason. It would probably be better to write things as an actual quadratic.

Comment: @robjohn  Thanks for your feedback. Good point , indeed. I need to note that "..it is reorganized to look like a quadratic polynomial (using colors)" .To completely understand the last part of your comment, may I ask if you agree with the following equality/identity? If we omit the term "Completing the square" in the terminological sense from the answer? $$
\begin{align}P(z):=\underbrace{\left(z^2+z+1\right)}_{\Delta_z<0}\left(z-\frac {1}{z^2+z+1}\right)^2+\frac{\overbrace{3z^2+3z+2}^{\Delta_z<0}}{\underbrace{\color{black}{z}^2+{z}+1}_{\Delta_z<0}}\end{align}
$$ Do you agree above identity ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not difficult to see that $z^3(z+1)=z^2z(z+1)\geq -1$ for all real numbers $z$. So,
$$f(z)=z^4+z^3+z^2+2z+3=z^3(z+1)+(z+1)^2+2\geq -1+0+2=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

A solution(maybe more difficult but easier to think)

Let $f(z)=z^4+z^3+z^2+2z+3$, then $f'(z)=4z^3+3z^2+2z+2$.

It is easily to see that $f'(z)$ have only one real zero.

Let it be $z_0$, so $4z_0^3+3z_0^2+2z_0+2=0$.

And $f'(0)=2>0$, so $z_0<0$

(This is because f is a monotonically increasing function)

And $f(z)\geq f(z_0)=z_0^4+z_0^3+z_0^2+2z_0+3=z_0^4+z_0^3+z_0^2+1-(4z_0^3+3z_0^2)=z_0^4-3z_0^2-2z_0^2+1=z_0^2(z_0^2-3z_0+2)+1=z_0^2(z_0-1)(z_0-2)+1>1$

Done!

Comment: By the way, you can draw a graph, or caculate $z_0$. By using computer we an get $z_0\approx -0.852$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

Let $P(x)$ a polynomial of even degree, (simple roots,)  positive leading coefficient, such that its derivative $P'(x)$ has exactly one real root $\xi$ ( for instance, if $P''(x) \ge  0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$). The minimum value of $P$ is $P(\xi)$, and, since the other roots are conjugate in pairs, it will have the sign of

$$\prod_{x_k, P'(x_k) = 0} P(x_k)$$

that is, the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $P$, and $P'$, or, using the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant)

$$(-1)^{\binom{n}{2}} \operatorname{Discr}(P(x))$$

Therefore, if the above is $>0$ then $P(x)>0$ on $\mathbb{R}$  ( this is a generalization of the case $P(x)$ of degree $2$).

In our case $n=4$, $P''(x)= 12 x^2 + 6 x + 2  >0$ on $\mathbb{R}$, $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ even, and the [discriminant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Discriminant%5Bz%5E4%20%2B%20z%5E3%20%2B%20z%5E2%20%2B2z%20%2B3%2C%20z%5D)
$$\operatorname{Discr}(P(x)) = 4345>0$$
so $P(x)> 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score -1):

First note $x=0$ is not a root. The idea is to split it into two parts and control the $\Delta=b^2-4ac<0$ for each part. For example,

$$f(z)=z^4 + \color{red}1\cdot z^3 + \alpha z^2+\beta z^2 +\color{blue}2\cdot z +3$$

where $\alpha+\beta=1$ and the coefficients of odd terms, which are $\color{red}1$ and $\color{blue}2$ will serve as the $b$ in our $\Delta$ for each part, namely
$$\color{red}1^2-4\alpha<0~\land~\color{blue}2^2-12\beta<0~\land~\alpha+\beta=1$$
hence

$$\boxed{\alpha>\frac14~\land~\beta>\frac13~\land~\alpha+\beta=1}$$

So we have plenty of space to choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$, for example, $\alpha=\beta=\frac12$, then we have

$$\begin{align} f(z)&=z^4 + \color{red}1\cdot z^3 + \frac12z^2+\frac12z^2 +\color{blue}2\cdot z +3\\
\\
&=z^2\underbrace{\left(z^2+\color{red}1\cdot z+\frac12\right)}_{\Delta=\color{red}1^2-4\cdot\frac12<0}+\underbrace{\left(\frac12z^2 +\color{blue}2\cdot z +3\right)}_{\Delta=\color{blue}2^2-4\cdot\frac12\cdot3<0} \end{align}$$

Therefore, $f(z)>0, \forall z\in \mathbb R$

Comment: Why I got two downvotes? This is a general method!

Comment: I didnt downvote you. I read your work friendly. Big brains are usually alone and they are fail.ure. Never mind.